# How to setup RSS in K2 plugin for joomla 3.x?

Tags: plugins, joomla, rss

I need to set up RSS feeds and search for tags with the text of the articles and pictures in Joomla 3. I used the default RSS joomla 3. It works fine. Further, I know that K2 is a search on the tags I need. After installing the plug-K2 RSS not see the aticles of K2. I can not find any kind of page where I can change the settings for K2 RSS. How can I setup the RSS feed in K2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it here: Components --> K2 --> button "K2 Parameters".
The general options are in the second tab: "Content" --> "RSS Channel" section but you can find options in tabs 1 and 7 ("Layouts and views" and "Advanced").

If you have any menu item associated with a K2 tag ot category you can also show or hide specifically in that menu item.

*P.S: Sorry if the tab names are slightly different, I works with a different language ;)*

Comment: I always prefer to use the English language for the same reason :)